# arrow.mul with odriplot3d to decrease arrow length

Tags: r, vegan

When I add environmental vectors to my 3d ordiplot one of the vectors extends beyond the NMDS1 axis, causing it to shift down. How can I reduce the relative length of this vector? I read the Rdocumentation and found `arr.len`, but this only changes the width of the arrow head, not its relative length.

[image]

Some sample data

```
cent1 <- structure(list(MHW = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("before", 
"during", "after"), class = "factor"), region4 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("north", "central", "north islands", 
"south"), class = "factor"), mpa_designation = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("smr", "ref"), class = "factor"), 
    NMDS1 = c(-0.0136854536146108, -0.0213969431531013, 0.11459701155485, 
    -0.0701744037821021, -0.0533507178649342, 0.078305514752002
    ), NMDS2 = c(0.0794882321818351, -0.0476376892369057, -0.0889694206421681, 
    0.075393697337676, -0.0500456169356214, -0.105236562428394
    ), NMDS3 = c(0.0274614713744096, 0.0418027560214913, 0.00113669343157737, 
    -0.0157942761283593, 0.0128859158958458, -0.0584235473524565
    ), centroid_type = c("smr before", "smr during", "smr after", 
    "ref before", "ref during", "ref after")), row.names = c("smr before", 
"smr during", "smr after", "ref before", "ref during", "ref after"
), class = "data.frame")


ef <- structure(list(vectors = structure(list(arrows = structure(c(0.1572782703955, 
0.446316585414283, -0.286402044252737, 0.196480042106197, -0.963027544775632, 
-0.812368711227128, 0.950667639523597, -0.97853010019109, 0.218726984308789, 
-0.375311314248998, 0.119184345492537, 0.0622449682622051), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(
    c("SST", "CUTI", "BEUTI", "MOCI"), c("NMDS1", "NMDS2", "NMDS3"
    )), decostand = "normalize"), r = c(SST = 0.156202538882316, 
CUTI = 0.111425532771979, BEUTI = 0.0134051599410927, MOCI = 0.258534845964422
), permutations = 999L, pvals = c(SST = 0.001, CUTI = 0.003, 
BEUTI = 0.705, MOCI = 0.001), control = structure(list(within = structure(list(
    type = "free", constant = FALSE, mirror = FALSE, ncol = NULL, 
    nrow = NULL, call = Within()), class = "Within"), plots = structure(list(
    strata = NULL, type = "none", mirror = FALSE, ncol = NULL, 
    nrow = NULL, plots.name = "NULL", call = Plots()), class = "Plots"), 
    blocks = NULL, nperm = 999, complete = FALSE, maxperm = 9999, 
    minperm = 5040, all.perms = NULL, make = TRUE, observed = FALSE, 
    blocks.name = "NULL", call = how(nperm = 999)), class = "how")), class = "vectorfit"), 
    factors = NULL, na.action = function (object, ...) 
    UseMethod("na.action")), class = "envfit")
```

Here is my code:

```
p1 <- ordiplot3d(cent1[,4:6], type="h",
                  scaling = "symmetric",
                  envfit=ef, arr.len = 0.1,pch=16, col=cent1$MHW)
text(p1, "arrows", col="blue", pos=3)
#ordilabel(p1$arrows*1.5)
text(p1$xyz.convert(cent1[,4:6]), rownames(cent1), pos=4)
points(p1, "points", pch=16, col=cent1$MHW, cex=2)
```

I am new to using `ordiplot`. Thank you!

Comment: There is obviously a bug in the code, and and arrows are scaled against wrong data (should use points, not "bp"). The code is in github, and pull requests are welcome.

Comment: @JariOksanen I don't think I have the technical knowledge to find the bug, but I'll take a look!